# Is Jersey client 3.1.3 jdk8 compatible?

Tags: java, jersey

I use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

When I migrate from 3.0.11 to 3.1.3, I get :

```
[ERROR] ....:[...] cannot access jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client
  bad class file: .m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/3.1.0/jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.1.0.jar(jakarta/ws/rs/client/Client.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
```

I run jdk 11 with target **jdk8**

Comment: This is trivial to google. All big libraries like Jersey publish version compatibility documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.

[Official documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/modules-and-dependencies.html#d0e560) says that Jersey targets Java 8 BUT in v3.1.3 they upgraded the `jakarta.ws.rs-api` dependency from v3.0.0 (see [this page](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/project-info/3.0.11/jersey/jersey-client/dependencies.html)) to v3.1.0 (see [this page](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/project-info/3.1.3/jersey/jersey-client/dependencies.html)).  This new version of `jakarta.ws.rs-api` targets Jakarta EE 10 instead of Jakarta EE 9 (new namespace) and also Java 11 instead of Java 8 (see [this page](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.1/)).  Perhaps they have not considered this issue.

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/5406) on GitHub.

Comment: The issue was closed on GitHub and doc was fixed.  Jersey client 3.1.3 requires jdk11. Bye